# Type 'Promise<[RowDataPacket[] |RowDataPacket[][] |OkPacket |OkPacket[] | ResultSetHeader, FieldPacket[]]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Post>'

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript, typeerror, mysql2

I have the following codes:

This is`db.ts`:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import mysql from "mysql2";

const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
});

export default pool.promise();
```

This is `Post.ts`:

```
import db from "../config/db";

class Post {
  title;
  body;
  yyyy:any;
  mm:any;
  dd:any;
  constructor(title: any, body: any) {
    this.title = title;
    this.body = body;
  }

  save() {
    const d = new Date();
    const yyyy = d.getFullYear();
    const mm = d.getMonth() + 1;
    const dd = d.getDate();

    const createdAtDate = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;

    const sql = `
    INSERT INTO posts(
      title,
      body,
      created_at
    )
    VALUES(
      '${this.title}',
      '${this.body}',
      '${createdAtDate}'
    )
    `;

    return db.execute(sql);
  }

  static findAll() {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM posts;";

    return db.execute(sql);
  }

  static findById(id:any): Promise<Post> {
    const sql = `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = ${id};`;

    return db.execute(sql);
  }
}

export default Post;
```

And the following is `postControllers.ts`:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import Post from "../models/Post";

const getAllPosts = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const [posts , _] = await Post.findAll();

    res.status(200).json({ count: (posts as any).length, posts });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

const createNewPost = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const { title, body } = req.body;
    const post = new Post(title, body);

    await post.save();

    res.status(201).json({ message: "Post created" });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

const getPostById = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  try {
    const postId = req.params.id;

    const [post, _] = await Post.findById(postId);

    res.status(200).json({ post: post[0] });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

export {getAllPosts , createNewPost, getPostById };
```

This code was a JavaScript project and was working before. I am trying to convert it to a TypeScript project. I have a problem with MySQL responses in the following line inside the `findById` function:

```
return db.execute(sql);
```

The ERROR says:

```
Type 'Promise<[RowDataPacket[] | RowDataPacket[][] | OkPacket | OkPacket[] | ResultSetHeader, FieldPacket[]]>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<Post>'.
```

Also another related problem here:

> ```
> const [post, _] = await Post.findById(postId);
> ```

The ERROR:

> Type 'Post' must have a 'Symbol.iterator' method that returns an
> iterator.ts(2488)

Comment: You use `db.execute(sql)` in many places. You shouldn't ask people to try to guess which one is giving you the error.

Comment: @NathanWiles: I thought this is a simple/general error that people with more experience understand it. BTW, I updated my question. The problem is inside the `findById` function.

Comment: Checkout this article: https://www.infoq.com/articles/typescript-mysql/ It seems that you need to decorate your class and column properties.

Comment: @BrunoMarotta: I've seen that article before but it uses an ORM that I don't want to use.

Comment: @BrunoMarotta: I am looking forward a simple template NodeJS-TypeScript project that uses `mysql` pool and `promise()` to connect and implement CRUD operations.

Comment: Can you put your sample project somewhere like codesandbox so that we can analyze it?